# Delete specific instances of characters from strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that looks as follows:

```
word1||word2||word3||word4
```

What is the best way to remove the 'extra' | between words in the string without getting rid of both of them?

The end product needs to look like:

```
word1|word2|word3|word4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are your requirements for "best"? Generally, including an attempt at solving the problem, posted as a [mcve] is the best way to ensure high-quality answers. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need guidance on writing good questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace`

```
str='word1||word2||word3||word4'
print(str.replace('||', '|'))
#word1|word2|word3|word4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex that matches one or more occurrences of the pattern:

```
import re
s='word1||word2||word3||word4'
re.sub('\|+','|',s)
# 'word1|word2|word3|word4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use str.replace :

```
('word1||word2||word3||word4').replace ('||', '|')
```

Answer (score 0):

below code should address your requirement.

```
str1="word1||word2||word3||word4|word6"
str1 = str1.replace("||","|")
print (str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `||` with `|` using `replace` functions.

```
str='word1||word2||word3||word4'
print(str.replace('||', '|'))
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: sure will do that.